# Get the sum of a DF using the date ranges in DF2

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have two dfs:

```
DF1 trip_sheet

date        trip_count
2019-07-01  1000
2019-07-02  2000
2019-07-03  3000
2019-07-04  3000
```

```
DF2: work_orders

date       bikeID part_name  repair_type
2019-07-01 bike1  basket     repair
2019-07-02 bike2  basket     repair
2019-07-04 bike3  basket     repair
2019-07-02 bike4  basket     adjustment
2019-07-04 bike5  basket     adjustment
2019-07-01 bike6  wheel      repair
2019-07-03 bike7  wheel      repair
```

I want to calculate the number of days between repairs/adjustments and get the sum of trip count. I am using MYSQL 5.7 and do not have the lead function to find the next repair/adjustment date.

I want my final output to look like this:

```
date       part_name repair_type days_between trip_count
2019-07-01 basket    repair      1            1000
2019-07-04 basket    repair      2            5000
2019-07-04 basket    adjustment  2            5000
2019-07-01 wheel     repair      2            3000
```

Comment: is there a good cause why for basket adjustment is only the end date and for wheel repair are only the start date , the result list doesn't make that much sense. if there are no deterministic rules.

Comment: DF2 is a list of work orders and this captures the timestamp of when a work order happened. The goal is to find out how many days the next work order will happen on that particular ```part_name``` and ```repair_type``` and to find the sum of trips that happened in between the two work_order dates ```days_between```

Comment: Yes gathered that but your prefere result doesn't work at all. think of an loop where you pick elements to display them for example in a stored procedure. So you get the first row it is aktion work day till now 0, second row also repair 1 day work, 3 row work 2 day period , then comes adjustment work 0 sencodn adjustment2 days. till now i haven't got a clue which data to pick ti get your result.